# load slack message history by an external web app

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm developing a web application which must load slack messages and work on it afterwards.

My question: what is the best way to develop an intermediary between slack and this web application to loads the messages directly after the user gives permission without creating a "slack app".

I saw [this](https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving) useful if we want to load only our own messages, but in my case I have to load the history messages inside my web application for each user who gives permission.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to retrieve data from Slack without creating a Slack app. You need to create an app that requests the types of permissions/scopes you require for `[conversations.history][1]` and/or the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api).The only way to access that information is with an app token and the only way to get a token is via app installation/authentication.

Comment: Thank you for replying me, 
I want to convert my web app to an Android app. This app will ask each user for the necessary permissions to access the conversations history on slack, so I want the app to be able to access each user's conversations history.
I created a Slack App and I was able to configure the environment but I'm still limited to my own messages only.

Comment: You should use the user token (xoxp) that belongs to each authenticated user to call conversations.history. You should be getting these tokens when a user authenticates successfully to your app. Make sure to store them and keep them private.